# hand_ik is hidden

Tags: armature, bones

Both hand_ik.R and hand_ik.L are not visible in the viewport. It was there for awhile and I must have done something to hide it. I've tried alt+H and the layer is active. What else can I try to make it visible?
Here's where it should be :
[image]

It should be on the palm

I can select in from the armature hierarchy, and then hit G and move it around
[image]

Layer is active :
[image]

Any ideas?